# Adverbs in mid postition and end position

Tags: adverbs, word-order

- I walk slowly
- I slowly walk

Both sentences are right because I  use adverbs in end and mid position, yes? Only one exception is *badly* which always goes in the end right?

Comment: Wrong. "I badly need a drink."

Comment: [Badly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/badly) can mean "in a poor or incompetent way" ("He played the piano badly") or it can be used as an intensifier ("I need that badly"). I've never heard a rule about badly, but I'd guess that the former meaning usually goes at the end and the latter can go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

*Surely*, *certainly*, *seldom*, *always*, and *hopefully* are just a few of the adverbs that can be placed before verbs, though some of them aren’t modifying the verb they proceed. In

> *He **seldom** drinks tea*,

the adverb does modify the verb. But in

> *He **certainly** drinks tea*,

it does not. This sentence means not that he drinks tea in a confident and unquestioning manner, but that we can be completely confident that he does drink tea.

Comment: Also " He only drinks tea" and "Only he drinks tea"